# creating a new folder with todays date on specific folder

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a new folder with todays date on specific given path:

```
string LocalDirectory = Directory.CreateDirectory(
    DateTime.Now.ToString("I:\\test\\final test\\snaps\\dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

But I receive this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' to 'string'

Answer (score 3):

As per [the documentation for Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), CreateDirectory returns a [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object, not a string.

So do this:

```
DirectoryInfo localDirectory = Directory.CreateDirectory(...
```

or this:

```
var localDirectory = Directory.CreateDirectory(...
```

*(which will basically do the same thing)*

Answer (score 1):

The code can be written as :

```
String Todaysdate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
if(!Directory.Exists("I:\\test\\final test\\snaps\\" + Todaysdate)
{
  Directory.CreateDirectory("I:\\test\\final test\\snaps\\" + Todaysdate); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Directory.CreateDirectory`  return  a `DirectoryInfo`  not string

you can try something like this

```
DirectoryInfo LocalDirectory = Directory.CreateDirectory(string.Format("I:\\test\\final test\\snaps\\{0}-{1}-{2}", DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Year));
```

to get  the path as  string

```
string strLocalDir = LocalDirectory.FullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is about the simplest way of creating a new folder named with todays date.

```
using System;


namespace CreateNewFolder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Todaysdate = DateTime.Now.ToString("-dd-MM-yyyy-(hh-mm-ss)");

            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("c:/Top-Level Folder/Subfolder/Test" + Todaysdate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Output of New folder name:***

***Test-02-05-2018-(11-05-02)***

I put the hours, minutes and seconds inside some parentheses for clarity.
You can take out any part of the date to return only the time/date portion you want to call your folder. If you don’t want to call it “Test-02-05-2018-(11-05-02)” but simply have todays date as the name; like “02-05-2018”,  then remove the “Test” from the “CreateDirectory” line but leave a blank space between -Subfolder/ and the closing quotation mark.  Like this:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("c:/Top-Level Folder/Subfolder/ " + Todaysdate);
```

Notice that I added a hyphen between the date parameters. This is just a visual separator for the date, you could also use a “space” as the separator.

I know this string is about 4 years old, but maybe this will help another newbie just starting out in C#.
Enjoy and share.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account the culture

```
var rootOutputDir = @"I:\test\final test\snaps";
var Todaysdate = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.Replace("/", "-"));
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(rootOutputDir, Todaysdate));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = Server.MapPath(@"/Content/");             
path = Path.Combine(path,DateTime.Now.ToString('ddmmyyyy'));
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
  {
     Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to create directories for the year and then the month inside the year folder. 
Here's what worked for me:

```
            public void CreateDirectory()
            {
            string strArchiveFolder = (@"\\fullpath" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "\\" +
                                  DateTime.Now.Month.ToString());
            if (!Directory.Exists(strArchiveFolder))
            {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(strArchiveFolder);
            }
```